# countdown timer isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I was trying to create a countdown with php and js.
I am learning js and php at the moment so I wanted to try and combine these two to make a countdown in which days, hours, minutes and seconds are included. the outcome of this code only tells me till when it runs but not how much time is left, so the countdown itself isn't working. can anyone help?

```
  <?php 
    $date = date('2022-02-26');
    $time = date('23:59:59');
    $date_today = $date . ' ' . $time;
    echo "it will run till" .$date_today;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //set the date we are counting to
    var count_id = "<?php echo $date_today; ?>";
    var countDownDate = new Date(count_id).getTime();
    //update countdown every second
    var x = setInterval(function(){
    //get today's date and time
    var now = new date().getTime();
    //find the distance between now and countdown date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    //time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60*24))/(1000*60*60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60))/(1000*60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60))/1000);
    // output the results in an elemtwith id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + 
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the countdown over, write some text
    if(distance<0){
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Expired"
    }
    },1000);
    </script><?php
    echo '<p id="demo" style="font-size:30px;"></p>';
    ?>
```

Comment: because your script run before the `p#demo` element exists, move it to the bottom will solve your problem or use the window on load event

Comment: @0nepeop1e I tried both and it didn't work

Comment: whats the log in your browser console? i am lazy to try your code, so i will just guide you the step to solve it

Comment: I forgot to look into my console and saw that var now = new date().getTime(); had an error in it. It was a simple spelling mistake. date should've been Date. thanks for the helps tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var now = new date().getTime();
```

spelling mistake, it should be

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
```

and now it works